# prove inequality by induction -- Discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove by induction that $∀n ≥ 3$ : $n^{2} + 1 ≥ 3n$

So I know I need to find my ***base case***, would it be:
$n=3$

Then calculate the RHS and LSH

RHS:$3(3)=9$ LHs: $3^{2} + 1= 10$ we see that the LHS is greater than or equal to the RHS.

Now for the ***inductive step***:

Assume that the formula is true for an arbitrary $∀n ≥ 3$
We now have to prove $n^{2} + 1 ≥ 3n$

This is where I get stuck, how can I prove this?

**Edit** : showing that the assumption applies to  $(n+1)^2+1≥3(n+1)$

Comment: You need to show that the assumption implies that $(n+1)^2+1 \geq 3(n+1)$

Comment: If $n\geq 3$, then $n^2\geq 3n$ so in particular $n^2+1>3n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to prove that under the assumption of the induction hypothesis, $$n^2 + 1 \geq 3n\tag{Inductive Hypothesis}$$ it follows that:

$$(n+1)^2 +1 \geq 3(n+1)$$

---

$$\begin{align} (n+1)^2 + 1 & = n^2 + 2n + 1 + 1 \\ & = (n^2+ 1) + 1 + 2n \\ &\geq 3n + 2n +1\tag{Use of Inductive hypothesis}\end{align}$$

Now it's up to you to argue that $$3n +2n +1\geq 3(n+1)= 3n + 3\quad \forall n\geq 3$$

To do this, convince yourself that $2n+1 \geq 3$ for all $n\geq 1$, though we only are concerned with $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Thanks, I am confused how you got $3n+2n$ because the original LHS is $n^2+1$ then wouldn't it be $(n^2+1)+1$?

Comment: We are making use of the assumption that $n^2 + 1\geq 3n$. Remember, we can use the assumption to prove that the assumption implies the case for $n+1$.

Comment: oh Ok so whenever we make an assumption is will always be $n+1$, that makes things a little clear now. 
so we now have $(n^2+1)+1$ which equals $n^2+2n+2$ and on the RHS we have $3n+3$ so now the inequality is $n^2+2n+2 ≥ 3n+3$?

Comment: Thanks, @user73985, for fixing my typo!!